# TypeScript - unable to import functions from a helper class

Tags: typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I am creating a TypeScript with Protractor framework and plan on using a set of helper functions (like isDisplayed(), isPresent(), isClickable(), etc) in a class and trying to reuse them in the spec files.

The end result will look something like this:

```
selectDropDown(element, option);
enterText(element, text);
```

However, I am having issues with creating the helper files as I am not able to export the functions from the helper file. Auto completion or auto suggestion is not working because the object is not accessible. :(

**helper.ts**

```
import { } from 'jasmine';
import { by, element, browser } from 'protractor';
import { By } from 'selenium-webdriver';

export class helper {
    async sayHello(name: String) {
        console.log('Hello ' + name);
    }
}
```

**sample-page.ts**

```
import { by, element, browser, WebElement } from 'protractor';
import { async } from 'q';
import { helper } from '../../helper'; //Importing the helper here

export class loginPage{

    help123: helper = new helper();
    help123. //Here the auto completion just doesn't happen.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: in sample-page.ts, your definition of helper:helper is missing var or let. Maybe typescript is confused by that. Also you should not call the variable helper, that might shadow the import. try something like var my_helper : helper = new helper()

Comment: Using var shows an error - [ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. [1068]

Comment: Still looking for help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new variable for it to work like that such as:

```
import { helper } from '../../helper';
export class loginPage{
  let help = new helper();
  help.sayHello('name');
}
```

A simpler solution might be to make the methods in your helper function static. If you have:

```
export class helper{
  static async sayHello(name:String){
    console.log('Hello '+name);
  }
}
```

You can then call this method like:

```
import { helper } from '../../helper';
export class loginPage{
  helper.sayHello('name');
}
```

Alternatively, in your helper class you could use a getter such as:

```
export class helper{
static get x() {return new this();} //could be named anything, I chose 'x'  
async sayHello(name:String){
    console.log('Hello '+name);
  }
}
```

Which would allow you to call the method like

```
import { helper } from '../../helper';
export class loginPage{
  helper.x.sayHello('name');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) but I am still not able to access the helper functions. As per your first solution, if I use a variable, "let" is showing an error - [ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. [1068] Static is not working either. Does this have something to do with the target in tsconfig? I am using  ES2017.

Comment: @williamtell Sounds like the issue is more with typescript than protractor. Sadly, I am not much help there